# Средство мониторинга сервера

Tags: nginx, zabbix, мониторинг, munin

Ищу систему мониторинга сервера. Из функционала нужно:

1. Мониторинг трафика Nginx(количество уникальных посетителей за
   последние 24 часа/неделю/месяц), статистика кодов состояния
   200/502/500/403 и так далее.
2. График количества http-запросов
3. Мониторинг потребления ресурсов сервера(нагрузка на CPU, количество
   занятой памяти)
4. Мониторинг трафика

Смотрел и Munin, и Zabbix. У первого нет мониторинга трафика и кодов состояния для Nginx, а у второго вообще вырвиглазный дизайн. Посоветуйте хотя бы web-based утилиту для мониторинга Nginx(1 и 2 пункты). Спасибо.

Comment: Я Заббикс использую. При большой БД Заббикса графики тормозят. По этому накрутил сверху графану и теперь все летает.